# How close a Busy Dialog "inside" of callback function from OData success function, which was created "outside"?

Tags: sapui5

Before I make an OData create entity, I show a busy dialog control showing "Processing..." menssage.
I want to close that busy dialog inside of success or error callback functions according to the situation, but I can't access to the busy dialog object... Someone can help me?

Code:

```
//Create Busy Dialog
var oBusyDialog = new sap.m.BusyDialog({
    title: this.getResourceBundle().getText("Processing"),
    type: "Message",
    afterClose: function() {
                oBusyDialog.destroy();
    }
});

//Trigger a POST request to the odata service...
this.getView().getModel.create('/MyEntitySet', myEntityObject, {
    success: function(){
                 oBusyDialog.close();
                 (...)
             }.bind(this),
    (...)
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bound your success function to **this** so you can store busy dialog instance as some property and it will be available inside your success function. Like this:

```
//Create Busy Dialog
this._oBusyDialog = new sap.m.BusyDialog({
    ...
    }
});

//Trigger a POST request to the odata service...
this.getView().getModel.create('/MyEntitySet', myEntityObject, {
    success: function(){
                 if (this._oBusyDialog) {
                   this._oBusyDialog.close();
                 }
                 (...)
             }.bind(this),
    (...)
});
```